# Eclipse RCP : Perspective switcher window dialog sort problem

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my application, when I select File->Open Perspective->Other it opens a dialog listing out all perspectives. My problem is that I want those perspectives to appear in a defined order (which they are not in this default perspective switcher).

This is the same dialog that pops up on clicking an icon displayed to the extreme left before anything else on the perspective bar.

There are a few implementations like [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/) that discuss how to disable perspective bar and make our own custom perspective switcher. General approach is to first disable perspective bar by altering ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java as shown below.

```
public void preWindowOpen() {   
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();   
configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false);   
}
```

But problem is that this also hides the entire perspective switcher (including perspective buttons that i need which i have arranged in a specific order).

So, is there a way to still have the perspective buttons displayed on the perspective bar and alter the order of the perspectives that are displayed in the default dialog(that opens on File->Open Perspective->Other)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, perspectives and views are always ordered according to their names, grouped by their categories. Maybe you can file an enhancement request for this at Eclipse Bugzilla.